# Ubuntu runs very slow

Tags: ubuntu, performance, freeze, troubleshooting

I have been using Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit for a month. It's working fine, but since two days ago it hangs more than ever, and it sometimes runs very slowly. For example, when a window closes it slowly fades out, and when it opens it slowly fades in.

What may be the reason for this, and what could be the solution?

Comment: Take a look at the system logs.

Comment: And try the command **top** to see what's hogging your system.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on when it is slow - is it slow after adding files to the system, and won't find your apps? If so this may be it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1175443

Is Firefox or any other apps with large menus, lagging? If so it's probably this one:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/968533
(Fix for Firefox at least is described on the page, requires using standard menu, not Ubuntu smart menus-on-top).

Other than that I don't know of anything that would make it slow all at once.